# Are there any statistical tests or measures for paired data with more than two groups?

Tags: repeated-measures, contingency-tables, paired-data, agreement-statistics

Are there any statistical tests or measures for paired data with more than two groups? My dependent variable is pretty flexible, but I'd really like to have five independent variables compared simultaneously. (This problem in general has come up for me many times in the past, and I've never been able to find a solution.)

In my current situation, I have five different operators who are scoring the same sample. I'm mostly interested in if one operator (Op A) is scoring differently than all of the other operators (Ops B-E). I think there's a big difference between these two scenarios, and I don't think testing Ops B-E against Op A separately is going to catch the difference:
*(For both scenarios, there are five samples total, and Op A scores higher than Ops B-E on all samples except those listed below.)*
1. Op B scores the same as Op A for sample number 2, and Op C scores the same as Op A for sample number 3.
2. Op B and Op C score the same as Op A for sample number 2.

The scores are ordinal with probably no more than three levels, but they are still useful if I convert them to binary scores. I'm also okay with treating the binary scores as continuous if that's the only way I can compare all five operators at once.

I'll actually have 10 samples each for three different types of samples if that's of any interest to anyone--I was simplifying for the example. The sample size can be changed, but of course the experimenters would prefer not to have to generate more samples :)

Here are tables of the two different example scenarios:

Scenario 1:
[image: Scenario1]

Scenario 2:
[image: Scenario2]

Answer (score 1):

I believe a repeated measures MANOVA is what I'm looking for! (Or repeated measures ANOVA for other situations.)

"Repeated measures" is the key phrase here to solve the general problem I've had in trying to find a test for paired data with more than two groups. That makes so much sense now--the word "paired" refers to two by definition, so of course I was having trouble applying it to several groups.

I'm still open to other analysis options, so please answer if you have any other ideas! (I'd rather be able choose the best approach from a set of options.)